# What is the name of the tool used to create an initial dent for drilling?

Tags: tools, drill, hole

I remember that during my DIY lessons at school, there was a tool used to help with positioning a drill bit. The tool was shaped like a large nail, and it was lightly hammered into the material at the point where the hole should be drilled. This would create a small dent in the material, which you would insert the drill bit into before drilling the hole. In this way, it prevented any slippage of the drill bit that might occur if the drill was just placed up against the flat surface of the material.

My question is: What is the name of this tool?

Comment: A center punch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a center punch.

[image]

There are also automatic center punches, which don't require a hammer.

[image: automatic center punch]

Comment: In the context of the OP it is only a center punch. To me if someone said hand me a punch I'd reach for a pin punch.

Comment: The automatic one is quite handy.